# Ruby on Rails working with SQL variables in c#

Tags: c#, sql, ruby-on-rails, sql-server

Well, I'll try to explain my problem. I use Ruby on Rails, and I need to work with C# variables that are queries of a BD (SQL Server). How can I to take these variables to work with RoR? Thanks.

Comment: Can you not query the SQL server in rails?

Comment: Mmm I don't know, but I can't do it . It's a security reason. I can't manipulate data from DB directly, only it can be consulted by a team mate that realize these queries with C#. I need to know how can use the data that my team mate get from the DB (Hospital DB).

Answer (score 1):

you will have to use Sockets.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_socket_programming.htm

That's a nice tutorial

Comment: Thanks so much for the tutorial Boltz0r.